# Redirect iPhone to an special theme

Tags: iphone, wordpress, themes

how can i redirect iPhone-users to an iPhone theme without a plugin or a theme swiutcher.
My idea is, that i detect the user agent (iphone) and this will be set something that i see an other theme in the iPhone.

Thanks and kind regards,

Peter

Comment: What's wrong with a plugin for this?

Comment: I don`t want to load more plugins than i need. but if u know aplugin pls post the url ;)

Comment: I too dislike using plugins when it could be built into my theme, but in this case it makes sense.

Comment: Your goal shouldn't be "reduce plugins at all costs", it should be "do it the right way". In this case, a plugin is the right way - much better than handling it elsewhere (like in the theme itself).

Answer (score 2):

A plugin is really the best way to do this. There's an already phenomenal one called [WPTouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/). It has a very functional free and a paid pro version.